How to convert the column with lists into one hot encoded columns?
Assume, there is one DataFrame such as following
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(1,4), 
                   'items':[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C']]})
df
        id  items
        1   [A, B]
        2   [A, B, C]
        3   [A, C]

Is there an efficient way to convert above DataFrame into the following (one-hot encoded columns)? Many Thanks in advance!
   id   items       A   B   C
    1   [A, B]      1   1   0
    2   [A, B, C]   1   1   1
    3   [A, C]      1   0   1


Hi @ZLi, this question is different from that one you just show because I have tried that method before I post my question here. get_dummies() can't be used here! because each id has difference length list items.

Hi @DaCard I am referring to df['items'].str.join(sep='*').str.get_dummies(sep='*')

I see! It is my bad, I should read it more carefully! By using that approach, I need to use pd.concat() to get the final table. Thanks

np :) or you can just use join df.join(df['items'].str.join(sep='*').str.get_dummies(sep='*'))

@DaCard: I have added a new solution, which is better than my initial one.

SOLUTION 1
A possible solution, whose steps are:

First, the explode function is used to transform each item of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values.

Then, the to_numpy method converts the resulting dataframe to a numpy array, and .T transposes this array.

The crosstab function computes a simple cross-tabulation of factors, which, in this case, are the transposed columns of the exploded dataframe.

The reset_index method is used to reset the index of the dataframe, turning the index into a column named id.

Finally, the original dataframe df is merged with this transformed dataframe using the merge function.


df.merge(
    pd.crosstab(*df.explode('items').to_numpy().T)
    .reset_index(names='id'))


SOLUTION 2
Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, the explode function is used to transform each item of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values.

Then, the pivot_table function is applied to reshape the data based on the unique values in the items column, aggregating the count of each id for every item. The fill_value=0 ensures that any missing combinations are filled with zeros.

The rename_axis method is used to remove the axis name for the columns.

Finally, reset_index is called to reset the index of the dataframe, turning the index into a column.

The original dataframe df is then merged with this transformed dataframe using the merge function.


df.merge(
    df.explode('items')
    .pivot_table(index='id', columns='items', values='id', aggfunc=len, 
                 fill_value=0)
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())


Output:
   id      items  A  B  C
0   1     [A, B]  1  1  0
1   2  [A, B, C]  1  1  1
2   3     [A, C]  1  0  1


OMG, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!

df['items'].str.join(sep='*').str.get_dummies(sep='*') I believe this from here is clearly better

Thanks, @ZLi, for your comment. Well, maybe the solution you mention is better than mine, but mine was the first solution that sprang on my mind!

@PaulS yeah I was going down the same path until I ran into that ;)

@ZLi: I guess my new solution is better than my initial one -- it is based on crosstab.

@PaulS, Thank you so much! I believe your solutions will help others as well. Thanks again!
